# Actionchains not working in selenium-python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, instagram

```
comment = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Ypffh')
next_feed = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"wpO6b")

    try:
      action = ActionChains(driver)
      action.move_to_element(comment)
      action.click()
      action.pause(3)

      df_comment = pd.read_excel(file_path[0], sheet_name = "Sheet1")
      real_comment = random.choice(df_comment["댓글"])
      comm = real_comment.split('-n')
      
      for i, c in enumerate(comm):
          c = c.replace("-n", " ")
          action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT)
          action.send_keys(c)
          i += 1

      action.pause(1)
      action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
      action.perform()  **// it works until here**
      
      time.sleep(5)
      
      action.move_to_element(next_feed)
      action.click()
      action.perform() **// it's not working**
```

I'm planning to open instagram links and leave comments from xlsx.

until leaving comments works fine, but clicking the next button (next_feed) isn't working

can you enlighten me what's wrong with the code?

cheers!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it's explained above. clicking next feed isn't working

Comment: I did not ask what is working and what isn't working. I asked what is the error? Is this the error `action.perform() **// it's not working` ? Do you understand what is an error or exception in computer science?